# Addressing UnsafeRedirectError on Devise registration confirmation url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, redirect, devise

**Summary**: When a new user registers,gets the confirmation email and clicks the link, the Devise generated confirmation URL throws an error:
`ActionController::Redirecting::UnsafeRedirectError (Unsafe redirect to "www.myapp.com/confirmed?account_confirmation_success=true", pass allow_other_host: true to redirect anyway.):`

This is because my app is the api backend (api.myapp.com) and the redirect url I'm sending the user to is the front end app which is on the main domain ([www.myapp.com](http://www.myapp.com)).

What's the best way to fix this issue?

The crude way IMO would be to override the confirmation controller and its show action and paste the original contents with a `allow_other_host: true` in the redirect. This seems hacky for, what I would consider, a fairly common scenario: Rails API with with devise auth.

Comment: Did you find a solution? The only way I found is to rescue from ActionController::Redirecting::UnsafeRedirectError, based on this source : https://blog.saeloun.com/2022/02/08/rails-7-raise-unsafe-redirect-error/

Comment: @gillien I wish I could help you but I'm so far away from this problem and tech stack that I dont remember much :( (Reminding myself to revisit posts and update them with answers next time).